# How can mesons have spin greater than 1?

Tags: particle-physics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, standard-model, mesons

My understanding was that a meson, being made of a quark and an antiquark (spin 1/2) could only have spin 1 or 0, by addition of angular momentum states. I just saw [an article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.7574) announcing the discovery of a spin 3 excited state of a meson. How can an excited state of a meson have spin greater than 1?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The total angular momentum of a meson is the sum of the spins of the two quarks and their orbital angular momentum. Excited states can have $L>0$ and therefore $J>1$.

Comment: But this doesn't seem to just be a meson with total angular momentum J=3; the article specifically says it has spin-3. Clarify?

Comment: Language barrier. "Spin *a*" for a meson is a **synonym** for *J*=*a*. The above answer is unimpeachable, and you may flesh it out from elementary meson spectroscopy combination rules, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meson#Spin.2C_orbital_angular_momentum.2C_and_total_angular_momentum

Comment: Your quark antiquark pair may combine into a spin singlet or triplet (spin=1), but when the orbital angular momentum between these two quarks is 3 in the first case, or 2 or 3 in the second, the total *J*=3.  You cannot distinguish between integral "spin" or "angular momentum" for a meson.